# Cocoa for the non-techinical

Tags: iphone, cocoa, macos

How would you describe and explain Cocoa in non-technical terms, with lots of analogies to common, everyday things. For example, imagine you are describing it to a 5-year-old who keeps asking why? at the end of each explanation. This would invariable delve into the theory of OO so it could get lengthy, but the concept is important to the 'why' of Cocoa.

Comment: Is your issue the Cocoa platform, or the Objective C language?

Comment: Are you teaching a night class in Bangalore or something?

Comment: "How would you describe and explain Cocoa in non-technical terms" ... why?

Comment: This reads like it should start with, "So I have this friend - not me, though - and he has this problem ..." ;-)

Comment: I was looking for something along the lines of Why's Poignant Guide to Ruby, but for Objective-C and Cocoa.

Comment: @annoyed: That seems like a lot to ask from someone writing an answer.    The Why's guide is a book, and the answers here tend to be a little shorter than that.  Also, that guide was written for a reader who is a little more experienced than a five-year-old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a library of pieces of computer code you can use in a program that allow your computer to do common things like show windows with controls in them and download things from the Internet.

That's Cocoa for the non-technical.

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa is a collection of common computer program parts that you can use to make your own program, kind of like Lego.  You need to figure out what you want to build, which pieces to use, and how to connect them.

Unlike Lego, you also need (get to?) to make some pieces of your own!

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa is the framework I use to write programs for Macs.